# add service reference fails with: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

A coworker was able to create a proxy with Apache Axis without issue.

Unfortunately I only have access to VS 2012 Express for desktop only.

I am getting this error when attempting to add a service reference:

```
There was an error downloading 'https://app.hostname.com/services/APP?wsdl/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 123.456.789.123:443
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://app.hostname.com/services/APP?wsdl'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://app.hostname.com//services/APP?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 123.456.789.123:443
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I'm getting the "works for me" treatment from the dev on the other side, and unfortunately I don't know the right questions to ask / how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall blocked communications.  What a stupid mistake